# Ajax after load menu buttons

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, load

Hy guys ! I have a problem with my menu from index.It appears that after i load another page with ajax , the menu isn't working anymore.Can you help ? Thanks
Is a problem that index and header1 have the same javascript ?

INDEX HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Lukcomputers</title>
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="fonts/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

<!--Menu-->
<div id="menu"><img src="img/menu/menu.png" width="900" height="517" /></div>
<div id="service" class="font-menu"  ><a href="#link" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFF;">SERVICE</a></div>
<div id="service-buton" class="font-menu-bold" ><a href="#link" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFF;">SERVICE</a></div>
</div>
<!--End of Menu-->

<div id="content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggle").hide();
    $('#service').click(function() { $('#toggle').toggle();$("#service").css('visibility', 'hidden');$("#service-buton").css('visibility', 'visible');});
    $('#service-buton').click(function() { $('#toggle').toggle();$("#service").css('visibility', 'visible');$("#service-buton").css('visibility', 'hidden');});


       $('#acasa').click(function() { 
       $.ajax({
           url:"header1.html",
           success: function(data) {
               $("#content").html(data)}
       });
       });

});
```

Header1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Lukcomputers</title>
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="fonts/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>


<!--Content-->
<div id="paragraf1" class="myriad">Instalare sisteme oferare<br />(WINDOWS, LINUX),<br />instalare aplicatii, back-up date.</div>
<!--End of  Content-->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is a bad practice. use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) if you want to load a specific part of a page into your current page. In your case, it is

```
$('#content').load('header1.html #paragraf1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your header1 html file shoud have only this line

```
<div id="paragraf1" class="myriad">Instalare sisteme oferare<br />(WINDOWS, LINUX),<br />instalare aplicatii, back-up date.</div>
```